# Почему точность модели останавливается на 50%

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Обучаю модель для классификации кошек и собак по изображению. Пробую написать полносвязную нейронную сеть, но при обучении точность на всех эпохах останавливается на 50%, пробовал добавлять дополнительные слои и менять параметры, но точность остается той же.
Код:

````
>from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator  >from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential  
>from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D  
>from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation,Dropout, Flatten, Dense  >from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img  
>from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array    
># Каталог с набором данных  
>data_dir = 'C:/Users/Mi/Desktop/Machine
>learning/train_cats_vs_dogs/train/'  
># Каталог с данными для обучения 
>train_dir = 'C:/Users/Mi/Desktop/Machinelearning/train_cats_vs_dogs/traini/'  
># Каталог с данными для проверки
>val_dir = 'C:/Users/Mi/Desktop/Machinelearning/train_cats_vs_dogs/val/'
> # Каталог с данными для тестирования 
>test_dir = 'C:/Users/Mi/Desktop/Machine learning/train_cats_vs_dogs/test/'
> # Количество элементов данных в одном классе 
>nb_images = 12500
> # Размеры изображения 
>img_width, img_height = 150, 150
> # Размерность тензора на основе изображения для входных данных в нейронную сеть
> input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
> # Количество эпох 
>epochs = 5
> # Размер мини-выборки 
>batch_size = 16
> # Количество изображений для обучения 
>nb_train_samples = 17500
> # Количество изображений для проверки 
>nb_validation_samples = 3750
> # Количество изображений для тестирования 
>nb_test_samples = 3750
> # Архитектура модели нейронной сети 
>model = Sequential() 
>model.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
>model.add(Dense(256,input_dim=784)) 
>model.add(Activation('relu')) 
>model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
>model.add(Dense(1))
>model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
>model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
>               optimizer='adam',
>               metrics=['accuracy']) 
>datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255) 
>train_generator =datagen.flow_from_directory(
>     train_dir,
>     target_size=(img_width, img_height),
>     batch_size=batch_size,
>     class_mode='binary') 
>val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
>     val_dir,
>     target_size=(img_width, img_height),
>     batch_size=batch_size,
>     class_mode='binary') 
>test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
>     test_dir,
>     target_size=(img_width, img_height),
>     batch_size=batch_size,
>     class_mode='binary') 
>model.fit_generator(
>     train_generator,
>     steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
>     epochs=epochs,
>     validation_data=val_generator,
>     validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
> # Проверка модели на тестовых данных 
> scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples//batch_size) 
>print("Аккуратность на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" %(scores[1]*100))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в выборе оптимизации нейронной сети. Заменил "adam" на "sgd".
https://keras.io/optimizers/

`model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
           optimizer='sgd',
           metrics=['accuracy'])`